# Maven connection to IDE

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, intellij-idea, ide

I am using **Maven** to use **Postrgres SQL** driver. Besides I am using **InteliJ IDEA Ultimatre Edition**, and, as I understood, **Maven** is included in **Ultimate version** initially. Correct me - *all I need, is to set dependencies, and connect PostrgeSQL to Java. I am not oblige to Download Maven* (except required Dependecie of course, I mean Maven as framework)? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating a new project, choose `Maven`. After the project is created, you will receive an empty Maven project structure with the pom.xml and a script `mvnw` of Maven Wrapper, which you can use (instead of `mvn`) to build your app.
Just add dependencies to the pom.xml and build.
The Maven Wrapper will do the work for you - download Maven into the project subdirectory and use it.